# Characterization of free product of groups by lifting property with respect to morphisms with right inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

A morphism $i : A \to B$ has the left lifting properties with respect to a morphism $p : X \to Y$ if and only if any commutative square with $i$ on the left and $p$ on the right has a diagonal lift making everything commute:

[image]

It is easy to see that the canonical inclusion of any group $G$ in a free product $G \to G * H$ has the left lifting property with respect to all morphisms with a right inverse. It made me think about the converse: is it true that for a morphism $f : G \to H$, there exists a group $G'$ and an isomorphism $\phi : H \to G * G'$ such that $\phi \circ f$ is the canonical inclusion if and only if $f$ has the left lifting property with respect to all morphisms with right inverse?

An interesting corollary, if this proposition is true, is that for a morphism $f : G \to H$, there is a free group $F$ and an isomorphism $\phi : H \to G * F$ such that $\phi \circ f$ is the canonical inclusion if and only if it has the left lifting property with respect to all surjective morphisms.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "left lifting property with respect to morphism with a right inverse" means: if $g\colon G\to K$ has a right inverse, then there exists a unique morphism $a\colon G*H\to K$ such that $g$ is the composition of the inclusion $G\hookrightarrow G*H$ and $a$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think he means: if $\phi: K_1 \to K_2$ has a right inverse, and we have a square with $K_1 \to K_2$ on the right and $G \to G * H$ on the left, then there is a unique diagonal map $G*H \to K_1$ making everything commute. (This latter claim is true and I can't prove the converse although I agree with the OP's suspicions that the converse is true.)

Comment: Yes, exactly as Hunter said.

Comment: I don't think "the obvious inclusion" necessarily works: just compose the usual inclusion with conjugation by a nontrivial element of $H$ in $G*H$; rather, you should express it as  saying that there is an isomorphism $H\cong G*K$ such that the composition with $f$ is the coproduct inclusion map.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I guess one way of stating it is that's "coordinate independent": given that there exists $G \to J$ with the left lifting property with respect to morphisms with right inverses, is there necessarily a group $H$ and an isomorphism $J \to G * H$ such that the given morphism $G \to J$ is the canonical inclusion?

Comment: @hunter Thank you, it is a good way of stating the proposition.

Comment: You did not say "unique" in the edit. If you don't require uniqueness for the diagonal map, then the embedding $\langle x^2\rangle\hookrightarrow F$, where $F$ is the free group on $x$, has the lifting property (without uniqueness for the diagonal map in general), and this is not an embedding into a free product.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin your example doesn't have the lifting property with respect to the projection $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, the canonical inclusion of a group in a free product doesn't have the unique lifting property in general.

Comment: Oops; I may have composed the one-sided inverse on the wrong side in my head...

Comment: The “obvious” thing to try is to let $N$ be the normal closure of $f(G)$ in $H$, and then construct a square with $G*(H/N)$ on the upper right and $H/N$ on the bottom right. The diagonal map will yield, *inter alia* that $f$ is an embedding.  Then one would try to show that the diagonal map is an isomorphism.